# How does a classifier work on categorical features?

Tags: python, classifier

I have a dataset with a categorical variable year which has the years:: 2015,2016,2017,2018,2019. What I am trying to understand is how does a classifier work on this feature? Let's take a decision tree or XGboost classifier. It goes ahead and does the split when it is the turn for this feature but if I have a test dataset whose year column has values such as 2020 or 2021, then what happens? what would the classifier do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful that this 'year' feature is not categorical, it's actually numerical (ordinal at least) because the values are *ordered*. It's important because the data can potentially contain some patterns following this order: for example, maybe the probability to have label Y with feature X tends to decrease along the years. If there is such a pattern, the model can use this information even in a year not seen in the training data, for example it can calculate that probability of Y with feature X is even lower in 2021.

This would be different with a categorical feature: for example, imagine you have a feature with a company name like 'Apple', 'Microsoft', 'Google', 'Samsung'. There's no natural order between these names, so they would be represented with one-hot encoding, as 4 independent features. In this case the classifier cannot do anything with a new name, because it cannot even represent any pattern involving a new name.

Comment: Thanks for your response, understood but suppose that I have a feature like company and we have 'Apple' and 'IBM' but 'Microsoft' pops up in the test set. This can happen in reality. So what should I do by then? How should I train my model? What kind of model do I need to train? What is the right approach in such circumstances?

Comment: @ Erwan @Brian Spiering in case of ordinal features, is the ordinal OneHot encoding of scikit learn the way to go? or there are other ways to tackle this? suppose that we have grades column, having values from A to F. Is this ordinal? if so, one hot encoder encodes them such that A: 0 and F:5 while I know A should get 5 points and F zero points. Do I need to refine the encoded values based on the requirement such that the highest rank/order gets the highest encoded value?

Comment: @RaminSalimi for question 1: it's just impossible to take into account new values of a categorical feature, at least with regular classification. The standard way to deal with it would to periodically re-train a new model using all the available (including recently annotated) data. Question 2: if the feature is ordinal, I would suggest a numerical encoding. yes, grades as letters would be an ordinal feature. imho one-hot encoding those would be really bad. In particular, an error between A and F would be the same as an error between B and C. With ordinal encoding these would be represented ...

Comment: ... as numbers, so the error between A=0 and F=5 would be considered larger than between B=1 and C=2. The model could use this information to minimize the global error level, but with OHE it can't.

Comment: What do you mean by saying an error between A & F would be the same as the error between B & C? How do we calculate the error? so I didn't understand because the difference between A & F should be larger than the difference between B & C, right? Also how should we do numerical encoding?

Comment: Also going back to the 'year' feature, I think to consider year as ordinal, there should be no way that the distance between any two numbers be not known. but we know the distance between 2017 and 2018 is one year and the distance between 2017 and 2019 is two years. Let's say in a race, first, second and third places. this can be entirely known as ordinal feature because we don't know the distance between first and second and third but about the 'year' feature', we do know the distance. So would it still be ordinal or interval variable? How to treat and encode interval features?

Comment: @RaminSalimi sorry, I used the word 'error' because I was thinking of target variable instead of a feature, the word 'difference' makes more sense: say e.g. that 2 instances are almost the same except the grade feature which has B in one but C in the other -> the instances are very close, and the model should use this. If on the contrary the grades are A and F, then the instances are quite different. This is why I would use numerical encoding for this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last question: you mean if the features contains only the rank/position 1, 2 instead of the actual year 2017,2019 for example?

Comment: The first question I have is how should we do numerical encoding for ordinal features? And the second question is about the definition of ordinal variables. I think a variable is ordinal when there is a rank/order between the values and also the distance between any two numbers is not known. For example, the distance between first and second may not be the same as the distance between second and third. Think of a 10k race. The winner might have run 30:00 minutes, second place might have run 30:01 minutes and third place might have run 400:00 minutes...........

Comment: ........Without the time data, we don’t know the relative distance between the ranks. In case of year column, we know the distance between each two year is 365 days and therefore, it is NOT an ordinal variable. It is indeed, in my view, an interval feature. The same reason, I think, is true regarding temperature and pressure. These two cannot be ordinal either and they are interval features like year. So it prompted this question as my third question: How should we encode interval variables such as year, temperature, or pressure?? ........

Comment: again, to make my point clear, let's think of grades. We cannot quantify the distance/difference between A & B, or A & D, or any other two grades. But in the case of year, we can quantify the difference/distance between each two years. or in the case of temperature, we can say the difference/distance between any two temperatures. Therefore, grade is ordinal and year, temperature, pressure are NOT ordinal and are interval features .Question I)How do we do numerical encoding for ordinal features? II)is the definition of ordinal/interval correct? |||)how do we do interval encoding?

Comment: @RaminSalimi you're going a bit too detailed for me! First about terminology: I'm not sure about the standard definition of 'ordinal', but to me in means that the variable has an order, i.e. any numeric is ordinal but not every ordinal is numerical. Anyway, to my knowledge a lot of things need a simplified representation for ML, and since virtually any ML algorithm requires numerical features that's why we do things like one-hot-encoding or basic numerical encoding: A=0,B=1, etc. Maybe there are some advanced representations that I'm not aware of, but I think the simplifications I mentioned...

Comment: .. are still the most [standard methods](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/423820/250483). So afaik the answer to your questions is disappointingly simple: everything is represented as numbers: ordinal A=0,B=1,... ; numerical 1997=1997, 2018=2018, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Year is better modeled as an ordinal feature, not a categorical feature.

A tree-based classifier will learn to split the data to create homogenous regions. For example, the model will learn that years less than 2017 are associated with a certain label and 2017 and greater years are associated with a different label.

Tree-based models do not extrapolate, thus will not make valid predictions for years outside of the observed range that appeared during training.

Comment: So based on your response, can we say that for cardinal features, the test set range has to be the same? or it is true only about the tree-based models? How about the categorical features, if in the test set, we observe something that did not exist amongst the categories of a feature in the train set, what happens then?